# Pass filename to scripts with autocomplete functionality

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Usually when I use file names within a script I mention the filename explicitly within the script, for example as shown below,

`#!/bin/bash
...
echo "<dynamic text>" >> process_log.log
...`

I was wondering if it is possible to pass filename to script like the following:

`./script_name.sh file_1 file_2 file_3`

with tab auto-complete functionality. (This would be very convenient !)

Does anybody has experience with this. Thank you.

---

`read` is one way to ask some input data but I feel it is cumbersome for multiple inputs and for long text.

Comment: Both are possible - passing filenames, using your example, you'd use $1, $2 and $3 to read the filenames inside your script. For auto-completion, `complete` will do it. If that (starts to) answer your question I'll write up a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that is what I am looking for, Please give details. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this script takes one mandatory argument, and two optional arguments. It'll exit (with an error) if you don't specify at least one argument. It doesn't do much besides that!

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "Missing filename: 1"
    exit 1
else
    file1=$1
fi
file2="$2"
file3="$3"
printf "File 1: %s\n" "$file1"
printf "File 2: %s\n" "$file2"
printf "File 3: %s\n" "$file3"
cat "$file1"
```

Save it as (for example) `script_name.sh` and set it to be an executable:

```
chmod u+x script_name.sh
```

Then run it like this:

```
./script_name.sh script_name.sh script_name.sh script_name.sh
```

It should display the three arguments you passed it (which are all "script_name.sh"), and then `cat` itself.

When I tried this, I experimented with tab completion - it worked fine automatically (it showed files and directories when I pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>). I didn't do anything to make it do this. However, if you wanted to only let your script work with certain files `complete -f -X '!*.png' script_name.sh` - that'll only show ".png" files when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Edit to add:

`complete` isn't run from the script itself (`script_name.sh` in the example above). Create a separate file (`completion_for_script_name.sh`, for example):

```
complete -f -X '!*.png' script_name.sh
```

Use `source` to load the completion into the current environment:

```
source ./completion_for_script_name.sh
```

Typically, you'd do this in your shell's profile, e.g. `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: Would be great to see an example of `complete` in action, i.e. where to put it in the script

Comment: @Jorstek - thanks, that's a good point. Does my edit fully address it?

Comment: It does. Much appreciated.